# ESXi 6.7 does not show all nics

Tags: vmware-esxi, intel

We bought a used Dell R730 server and installed the customized ESXi ISO. VMs are running, everything is displayed correctly.

There are 2 network cards in the server, one Intel X520 1G and one Intel 82599 10G SFP+. But here only the 1G Nic is displayed and also gets an IP address. The 10G Nic is not displayed in the WebClient and Console as a VMNIC.

[image]

But under PCI devices the network card is detected.

[image]

The 10G Nic is supported under VMware (compatibility list)

[image]

But the drivers seem to be loaded:

[image]

What can I do so that the ESXi host recognizes the NIC correctly and is assigned an IP address? What other possible solutions are there?

Comment: Your first screenshot shows that the NIC has been recognized. What makes you think it hasn't? Did you attach the NICs to your vSwitch?

Comment: Because it is not displayed as VMNIC and therefore I cannot add it to the Vswitch

Comment: Did you install Dell customized image of ESXi?
https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-sg/sln288152/dell-emc-customized-image-of-vmware-esxi-availability-and-download-instructions?lang=en

Comment: yes, the Dell customized images is installed

Comment: Have you opened a SR?

Comment: no, i guess its more a problem with ESXi

Comment: I meant an SR with VMware

Comment: Just to be clear, if you SSH to the ESXi node and run esxcfg-nics -l, does it list all the NICs?